# Python : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'

Tags: python

I'm getting following error while running the script and the script is to get the SPF records for a list of domains from a file and i'm not sure about the error,Can any one please help me on this issue ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket
import dns.resolver
import re


def getspf (domain):
   answers = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'TXT')
   for rdata in answers:
     for txt_string in rdata.strings:
       if txt_string.startswith('v=spf1'):
         return txt_string.replace('v=spf1','')

f=open('Input_Domains.txt','r')
a=f.readlines()
domain=a
print domain
x=0
while x<len(domain):
        full_spf=getspf(domain)
        print 'Initial SPF string : ', full_spf
        x=x+1
f.close()
```

Input_Domains.txt

```
box.com
bhah.com
cnn.com
....
```

Error Message:

```
['box.com\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 22, in <module>
    full_spf=getspf(domain)
  File "sample.py", line 10, in getspf
    answers = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'TXT')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1027, in query
    raise_on_no_answer, source_port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 817, in query
    if qname.is_absolute():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`domain` is a list, not a string. You want to pass *elements* of `domain` to `getspf`, not the entire list.

```
f=open('Input_Domains.txt','r')
a=f.readlines()
domain=a
print domain
x=0
while x<len(domain):
        # domain[x], not domain
        full_spf=getspf(domain[x])
        print 'Initial SPF string : ', full_spf
        x=x+1
f.close()
```

You also don't need to read the entire file into a list at once; you can iterate over the file one line at a time.

```
with open('Input_Domains.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        full_spf = getspf(line.strip())
        print 'Initial SPF string : ', full_spf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot chepner and Solved it !

Answer (score 0):

When you run `getspf (domain)`, `domain` is the whole list of domains in your file.

Instead of

```
f=open('Input_Domains.txt','r')
a=f.readlines()
domain=a
print domain
x=0
while x<len(domain):
    full_spf=getspf(domain)
    print 'Initial SPF string : ', full_spf
    x=x+1
f.close()
```

do

```
with open('Input_Domains.txt','r') as domains_file:
    for domain in domains_file:
        full_spf = getspf(domain)
        print 'Initial SPF string : ', full_spf
```

Comment: Thanks You Deepspace.